# Detect/receive multiple key-presses at the same time in DOS?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16, tasm, dosbox

I'm in the middle of writing air hockey in tasm and I have encounter a problem which is how I get two keys/clicks at once because I need to get both click at once to move both players in one time and Im trying a lot but I don't think I have a way to doing it.
I heard that I need to read from the buffer directory and see what keys are there and read each one individually but I don't really know how to do this.

Comment: Are you able to get one key at a time?

Comment: Yes, it's it 16h or 21. But I need to get 2 keys at once - not happening, get only the first, and then I need to call two procedures to move two players at almost once

Comment: You might want to add information about the OS, platform etc.

Comment: I'm writing in TASM8086 in windows, I'm using dosbox

Comment: Post the code you have so others may give you opinion and suggestions.

Answer (score 6):

Do you mind working with scancodes?

I know this is not the simple, drop-in, solution you were looking for but I'm afraid there is none.
So I'm writing this in the hope that, if not you, some other troubled coder can find something useful.

I also know you write for TASM but I forgot that and started with NASM, converting however should be very easy (just add segments declarations, take out the segment register from the brackets and add *PTR*).

---

It seems that from an hardware perspective the keyboard repeats only the **last pressed key**<sup>1</sup>, so if two players are pressing two keys, only one is actually sent by the keyboard.
However the software handle multiple keys at once everywhere, *how do they do it?*

The trick is that the keyboard sends **two codes** (*scancodes*) when a key is pressed: one when the key goes **down** (and many others while it is kept down) and one when it is **released**.
The software can thus tell when a key is down without further notice from the keyboard<sup>2</sup>.

I cannot find any [interrupt service](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/int.htm) that handle key up and down events.

**The only solution is handling scancode directly.**

While the [8042 chip](http://zet.aluzina.org/images/d/d4/8042.pdf) is very simple, there is not need to get dirty with IO instruction.
Without explaining how the 8259A and the IRQ mapping works, it's enough to say that **the interrupt `15h/AH=4fh` is called with the scancode in `AL` when a key is pressed/released.**

We can intercept that interrupt and check if the scancode is for a key down or a key up.
Release scancodes have *bit7* set.
We can have an array of 128 bytes, each for any possible scancode value (*bit0-6*)<sup>3</sup> and store in each element `0ffh` if the scancode indicates a press or `00h` if it indicates a release.

It is also useful keep a count of the processed scancodes, so a program can wait for new scancodes with trivial arithmetic.

---

Now, I imagine you are still confused.
I have written a demo.

The program below, for NASM, waits for you to press **both** *a* and *d* keys to exit.
**Warning** Since we are using scancodes, this is keyboard layout dependent!

```
BITS 16
ORG 100h        ;COM

 ;Setup ISR for the scancode 
 call init 

 ;Clear screen
 mov ax, 03h
 int 10h 

 ;Print command
 mov ah, 09h 
 mov dx, strCommand
 int 21h 

_main:
 ;Wait for a change in the scancode tables
 call wait_for_scancode
 ;Remove unused keystrokes
 call remove_keystrokes

 ;Check if a is pressed 
 mov al, 1eh           ;a
 call is_scancode_pressed
 jz _main 

 ;Check if 'd' is pressed 
 mov al, 20h           ;d 
 call is_scancode_pressed
 jz _main 

 ;Both are pressed, print bye and ...
 mov ah, 09h 
 mov dx, strDone
 int 21h 

 ;... restore the ISR and ...
 call dispose 

 ;... exit
 mov ax, 4c00h
 int 21h

 strCommand db "Press 'a' and 'd' to exit", 13, 10, 24h 
 strDone    db "Bye",13,10,13,10,24h 

 ;Ll  Ll  Ll  Ll  Ll  Ll  Ll  Ll  Ll  Ll  Ll  Ll  Ll  Ll  Ll  Ll  Ll  Ll  Ll  L  
 ;  Ll  Ll  Ll  Ll  Ll  Ll  Ll  Ll  Ll  Ll  Ll  Ll  Ll  Ll  Ll  Ll  Ll  Ll  Ll
 ;Ll  Ll  Ll  Ll  Ll  Ll  Ll  Ll  Ll  Ll  Ll  Ll  Ll  Ll  Ll  Ll  Ll  Ll  Ll  L

 ;S C A N C O D E   F U N C T I O N S

 ;Set the ISR 
init:
  push ax  

  mov ax, cs
  mov WORD [old_isr_15 + 02h], ax          
  ;old_isr_15 is now a far pointer to new_isr_15

  call swap_isr_15          ;Swap the current isr15 with the one in old_isr_15

  pop ax 
  ret

  ;Restore the original ISR 
dispose:
  call swap_isr_15          ;Swap the current isr15 with the one in old_isr_15                  

  ret  

  ;Swap the pointer in the IVT for int 15h with the pointer in old_isr_15
swap_isr_15:
  push eax
  push es 

  xor ax, ax 
  mov es, ax 

  cli

  mov eax, DWORD [es: 15h*4]
  xchg eax, DWORD [old_isr_15]
  mov DWORD [es: 15h*4], eax 

  sti

  pop es 
  pop eax

  ret  

  ;Wait for a change in the scancode table
wait_for_scancode:
 cli                           ;Prevent the ISR from messing things up 

 ;At least one scancode processed?
 cmp WORD [new_scancode], 0 
 jne _wfs_found                ;Yes

 ;No, restore interrupt so the CPU can process the prending ones
 sti
jmp wait_for_scancode

 ;New scancode, decrement the count and restore interrupts
_wfs_found:
 dec WORD [new_scancode]
 sti 

 ret

  ;THe BIOS is still saving keystrokes, we need to remove them or they 
  ;will fill the buffer up (should not be a big deal in theory).
remove_keystrokes:
 push ax

 ;Check if there are keystrokes to read.
 ;Release scancodes don't generate keystrokes 
_rk_try:
 mov ah, 01h 
 int 16h
 jz _rk_end      ;No keystrokes present, done 

 ;Some keystroke present, read it (won't block)
 xor ah, ah 
 int 16h
jmp _rk_try

_rk_end:
 pop ax 
 ret 

 ;Tell if a scancode is pressed
 ;
 ;al = scancode  
 ;ZF clear is pressed 
is_scancode_pressed:
  push bx

  movzx bx, al 
  cmp BYTE [scancode_status + bx], 0 

  pop bx 
  ret 

 ;AL = scancode 
new_isr_15:
 ;Check for right function
 cmp ah, 4fh
 jne _ni15_legacy

 ;Save used regs
 push bx
 push ax


 movzx bx, al            ;BX = scancode 
 and bl, 7fh             ;BX = scancode value

 sar al, 07h             ;AL = 0ffh if scancode has bit7 set (release), 00h otherwise
 not al                  ;AL = 00h if scancode has bit7 set (release), 0ffh otherwise

 ;Save the scancode status
 mov BYTE [cs:bx + scancode_status], al 
 ;Increment the count
 inc WORD [cs:new_scancode]

 pop ax
 pop bx 

_ni15_legacy:   
 ;This is a far jump, in NASM is simply jmp FAR [cs:old_isr_15]
 ;Ended up this way for debug
 push WORD [cs: old_isr_15 + 02h] 
 push WORD [cs: old_isr_15] 
 retf

 ;Original ISR
old_isr_15                      dw new_isr_15, 0  

 ;Scan code status table
scancode_status     TIMES 128   db 0
 ;Scan code count 
new_scancode                    dw 0
```

All you need to use is:

- `init` to set up the scancode snooping.
- `dispose` to tear down the scancode snooping.
- `is_scancode_pressed` to know if a key is being held down.

Everything else, including `wait_for_scancode` and `remove_keystrokes` is accessory and is there just to make your program behave very nice.

If you want to find the scancode associated with a key, you can use [this other program](http://pastebin.com/t76idZes) that show you a table with the pressed scancodes (press *ESC* to exit).
For example, if I press *a* and *d* I get the values used in the demo

[image: Me pressing 'a' and 'd']

It is just a variant of the demo above.

---

<sup>1</sup>I create [this](http://pastebin.com/zrGsMTis) boot program (intended for NASM) to test my hypothesis, at least in my hardware.

<sup>2</sup> Effectively speaking the repeat feature is useful only in typing software, every other application, like games, that explicitly check for keys status don't need it.

<sup>3</sup> There are actually extended (multi byte scancode) but they are ignored here. Stick with plain keys!

Comment: sometimes the terms make (button down makes a connection) and break (button released, breaks connection) are used. and absolutely this is the only way to do it you have to watch for makes and breaks for the keys you are interested and keep your own local state table, and then run your program off of that state table for keys that can be pressed "at the same time", for other keys, quitting the game or whatever, just the make should do.